# Adding CSV with state plane coordinates instead of decimal degrees to ArcGIS online?

Tags: arcgis-online, csv, google-docs

My goal is to use [this method](http://communityhub.esriuk.com/geoxchange/2014/7/11/using-google-docs-in-your-arcgis-online-maps.html) of using google sheets with ArcGIS online to update my web map automatically with new points which are added to the google sheet csv.

My problem is according to [this document](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/csv-gpx.htm), coordinates have to be in decimal degrees. The points I want to bring in are surveyed in state plane northing and easting. It would defeat the purpose of updating it automatically if I have to create a shapefile out of the csv first in order to get decimal degrees fields.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to find a formula to calculate decimal coordinates in google sheet
[image: idea]

I am not sure if it works but you can try

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding formulas, do you know of any resources?

Comment: there is some recource about this subject with spread sheet added: https://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/UsefulData/UTMFormulas.HTM
It is not that simple as I showed in the picture :)